# Compare a File and Database Table with Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho

I am still getting to grips with Pentaho and the Data Integration Tool.

I am building a Data warehouse of users with their associated roles. We get a feed on a daily basis that needs to be inserted into the database. I am comfortable with this but the problem comes in when i need to check against the database for changes in the users status. For instance a feed comes in today with User X, User X has a Status of Active. When a new feed comes in a week later, User X status has changed to inactive in the feed but not in the database as yet. How would I go about comparing what is in the database currently and what is in the new feed file and report on that?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare these 2 data sets with the "Merge Rows" step.

See: also: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+Rows